# Constrain a general quadric to be a paraboloid?

Tags: quadratic-forms

Given a general quadratic, where not all of the coefficients are 0:

$$ \begin{array}{lr} Ax^2 + By^2 + Dxy + Gx + Hy + J = 0 & (1) \end{array}$$

We can think of this as a map from the set of viable coefficients in ${\rm I\!R}^6$ to the set of manifolds in ${\rm I\!R}^2$.

Restricting our equation to a parabola restricts the angle at which the plane can intersect the cones, and so this results in a variable that is not "free".  Formally, this is relatively [easy to obtain](https://brilliant.org/wiki/conics-discriminant/) as $D^2 - 4AB = 0$.  So, we could set $A = D^2/(4B)$ and "do away" with one of the variables, obtaining a map instead from ${\rm I\!R}^5$ to the set of manifolds on ${\rm I\!R}^2$.

In 3D, the equivalent thing is a quadric surface, the points of which satisfy the following general equation:

$$ \begin{array}{lr} Ax^2 + By^2 + Cz^2 + Dxy + Eyz + Fxz + Gx + Hy + Iz + J = 0 & (2) \end{array}$$

I suspect that constraining this equation to be a paraboloid gives a similar restriction on the variables, but it is not entirely clear how I might perform a substitution to "do away" with any of the variables.  Is there a way that I can rewrite equation (2)  in only 9 coefficients to constrain the problem to paraboloids?

Comment: Which paraboloid ? Elliptic or hyperbolic ?

Comment: Elliptic, preferably.  My specific use case is that I am fitting a quadric surface to some points, and there are discontinuities in the map from coefficients to manifolds when changing between the various types of quadrics.  There is also a discontinuity between elliptic and hyperbolic paraboloids, so restriction to Elliptical ones would be ideal.

Comment: Even though equation (1) has six coefficients, you really only have five degrees of freedom.

Comment: You don’t know that $B\ne0$ when you “do away” with a variable in (1). What you can do to reduce the number of coefficients in the general case is to rewrite the quadratic part as $(\alpha x+\beta y)^2$.

Comment: @amd "the quadratic part can be written as the sum of two squared linear terms corresponding to the principal axes" this seems to suggest that I can just *start* with my equation in this format, which would be sufficient for my purposes.  I will contemplate this.

Comment: In a similar way to the parabola, the quadratic part of an elliptic paraboloid’s equation can be written as the sum of two squared linear terms corresponding to the principal axes. This comes from looking at the canonical equation $x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2-z=0$. I’m not entirely sure that this will lead to a reduction in the number of parameters, although it seems like it ought to. You can try completing the squares in the original general equation.